# append data from SharePoint to Access 

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access

We have many SharePoint sites that our users update, and import the tables into Access 2007.

We only want to add the new data each week.

How can we upload the new data without overwriting the existing data in the Access tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to link to the SharePoint lists instead of importing them into Access.  Using links, all the data would remain in SharePoint, but be accessible to your Access application, so you needn't bother with synchronizing copies of the data in Access.

If that solution isn't feasible for your situation, you could still create links to the SharePoint lists and use them for what the Access UI calls "append queries".

```
INSERT INTO AccessTable (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM SharePointList
WHERE date_of_origin > Date() - 7;
```

So an append query could work if you can build a WHERE clause to distinguish which of the SharePoint data rows are "new".  That could well require a more complex SQL statement; I chose the example above because it is so simple.

Comment: Thank you Hans.  I don't think we can link all the tables but I'll work with an append query on the ones we can't